# Android Studio throwing IDE Error when trying to open Project Structure

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5, android-studio-3.6

In my one (and only) project, when I try to open the "Project Structure" dialog (File -> Project Structure), the window does not open and a little red popup appears that reports "IDE Error".

When clicking on the error, I am seeing two throwables listed, the message is the same, but stacktrace is different. Message reads:

`java.lang.Error: Incomplete or corrupted installation - "C:\Program Files\prebuilts\studio\jdk\win64" directory does not exist`

I am not sure where it is getting that directory from, as I've never installed anything in 'prebuilts' (indeed, the folder does not exist).

This happens in v3.5 and the preview v3.6 of Android Studio, as well.

Any way to address this and be able to get the Project Structure dialog up? (i.e. Stop it looking for something in 'prebuilts')?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in idea.properties (Android Studio -> Help -> Edit custom properties):

```
android.test.embedded.jdk=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_271
```

With your JDK location.